# Show Next Select Option based on Previous Selection value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am have a form that contains two selections. I am wonder for how to display the Second selection option by based on what value from the previous selection.

My form html is

```
<option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0" selected="selected" data-sf-depth="0" value="">All Items</option>
<option class="sf-level-0 sf-option-active" data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0" value="2 A">2 A</option>
<option class="sf-level-0" data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0" value="4 B">4 B</option>
```

```
<option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0 sf-option-active" selected="selected" data-sf-depth="0" value="">All Items</option>
<option class="sf-level-0 " data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0" value="25 A">25 A</option>
<option class="sf-level-0 " data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0" value="40 A">40 A</option>
<option class="sf-level-0 " data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0" value="63 A">63 A</option>
<option class="sf-level-0 " data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0" value="80 A">80 A</option>
<option class="sf-level-0 " data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0" value="100 A">100 A</option>
```

For Example:

If user select the first is value="2 A"

The second selection will display only some option for example only

```
<option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0 sf-option-active" selected="selected" data-sf-depth="0" value="">All Items</option>
<option class="sf-level-0 " data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0" value="25 A">25 A</option>
<option class="sf-level-0 " data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0" value="40 A">40 A</option>
```

This form is generate by a WordPress plugin. So I can't add any class name to the option.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you generalize the rule to filter out the second set of options.

Comment: Do the selects at least have different id's? Would be nice to have your entire HTML for the selects instead of just the options

Comment: Hi,
the selected has no id

<select name="_sfm_rc_up_63ka_poles[]" class="sf-input-select" title="">
   
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0" selected="selected" data-sf-depth="0" value="">All Items</option>
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-option-active" data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0" value="2 A">2</option>
    <option class="sf-level-0" data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0" value="4 B">4</option>
</select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is admittedly ugly but it does work assuming that your selects have different ID's, if they don't this won't work https://jsfiddle.net/calder12/jpec347e/1/

Basically what you're going to do is create arrays of values for each option in the first select box, then an array for all the options, then dynamically populate the second select box based on the value of the first.

```
var allOptions = ["25 A", "40 A", "63 A", "80 A", "100A"];
var twoAOptions = ["63 A", "80 A", "100A"];
var fourBOptions = ["25 A", "40 A"];

$("#select1").on("change", function() {
    if($(this).val() === "2 A") {
    $("#select2").find("option").remove().end().append('<option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0 sf-option-active" selected="selected" data-sf-depth="0" value="">All Items</option>');
    for(i=0; i <= twoAOptions.length -1; i++){
        var option = '<option class="sf-level-0 " data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0"  value="'+twoAOptions[i]+'">'+twoAOptions[i]+'</option>';
        $('#select2').append(option);
    }
  } else if($(this).val() === "4 B") {
    $("#select2").find("option").remove().end().append('<option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0 sf-option-active" selected="selected" data-sf-depth="0" value="">All Items</option>');
    for(i=0; i <= fourBOptions.length -1; i++){
        var option = '<option class="sf-level-0 " data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0"  value="'+fourBOptions[i]+'">'+fourBOptions[i]+'</option>';
        $('#select2').append(option);
    }
  } else {
    $("#select2").find("option").remove().end().append('<option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0 sf-option-active" selected="selected" data-sf-depth="0" value="">All Items</option>');
    for(i=0; i <= allOptions.length -1; i++){
        var option = '<option class="sf-level-0 " data-sf-count="-1" data-sf-depth="0"  value="'+allOptions[i]+'">'+allOptions[i]+'</option>';
        $('#select2').append(option);
    }
   }
})
```

Like I said, this isn't a terribly elegant solution, but it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you very much Rick!
I am really grateful  for your help. I understand that the code maybe not look good because of the html has no id for something related. However, because of my selection fields have not too much options. So, I can do it follow you suggestion.

Thank you so much again! :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)